# Why BigDecimal scale not working in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scale, bigdecimal

I was struggling to get the right results with `BigDecimal` for several hours.

I have the number 7.7049. I want to first round to 3 digits. I will get 7.705. Then round this more, to 2 digits. I should get 7.71.

I tried this:

```
BigDecimal(result).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) //instead of 2 can be any other number
```

But I get the wrong number: `7.70`.

I have tried different modes. I have also tried `valueOf(result.toDouble())` and nothing works.
The problem here looks like `setScale` working with only 2 last digits after `.` and ignoring others.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATED:**

More examples:

7.7019 must be 7.70 | 7.7052 must be 7.71 | 7.7071 must be 7.71 | 7.7030 must be 7.70

Comment: How about `RoundingMode.CEILING` ?

Comment: @jrook Nope. I need simple math rounding, not always UP. I mean `7.7049` must be `7.71` but `7.7039` must be `7.70`

Comment: Do you know what `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` does? Why would you *expect* 7.7049 to become 7.71? "Normal" rounding will make it become 7.70 because the ,049 is closer to ,0 than it is to ,1

Comment: I don't think there is a rounding model that will make 7.7049 round to 7.71 but 7.7039 to 7.71, because that does not make sense.

Comment: Please give more examples to clarify what you really want to do. `7.030 7.040 7.041 -7.039`, etc. Also, as other commenters have noted, this is not *normal* math rounding even if it is achievable somehow. You can consult https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Sounds like you want to round `7.7049` to `7.705` first, then round that to `7.71` - Rounding `7.7049` rounds down to `7.70`

Comment: @Dioxin Yeah, like this, but with one action if it is possible

Comment: There is no one action that will do that rounding the way you have described, because that is such an unusual and nonstandard way of rounding.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thx a lot for the clear comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first round the first 3 digits, and then the first two digits to get what you want.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("7.7039")
    .setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
    .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Results are compatible with your test cases. I have not tested this for negative numbers, and it will probably not yield expected results for numbers with arbitrary precision.

You can consult [the docs on RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) and use this idea to perhaps come up with a scheme that rounds numbers in the non-standard way you want.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is simple. I have the number 7.7049. When I want to round
> to 3 digits after . I will get 7.705 but when I'll round this more, to
> 2 digits I should see 7.71.

You have already mentioned what you need to do i.e. round first with scale `3` and then with scale `2`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7019, 3, 2));
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7052, 3, 2));
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7071, 3, 2));
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7030, 3, 2));
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7049, 3, 2));
        System.out.println(roundNumber(7.7039, 3, 2));
    }

    static BigDecimal roundNumber(double num, int scaleRound1, int scaleRound2) {
        return new BigDecimal(num).setScale(scaleRound1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(scaleRound2,
                RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7.70
7.71
7.71
7.70
7.71
7.70
```